# large number (bigint) for post ID issue in database

Tags: database, rest-api, wp-insert-post, id

the ID of my latest post is `796978707878960002`.

I manually created it using the code below:

```
wp_insert_post(array(
    'import_id' => 796978707878960002,
    'post_title' => '-test'
));
```

Now, whenever I want to create a new post from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B3cSTGyMx2xoPAwkSzCvdvLlPVH8LaLM/view?usp=drivesdk), I get the following error:

```
WordPress database error: [Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine]
```

[image]

or the page gets blank; in this situation (blank page) the auto draft of the posts is created in the database

[image]

this error is also shown in console

```
{
"code": "rest_post_invalid_id",
"message": "Invalid post ID.",
"data": {
    "status": 404
}
```

from this `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/796978707878960000?context=edit&_locale=user`

I don't know why the rest-api should get 79697870787896**0000** while my latest post ID is 79697870787896**0002**

note: if the ID is not a big number, let's say 7000, there is no issue in creating posts at all.
how can it be fixed?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please upload images directly to the post for improved accessibility and security. Also, please do not post images of text: please copy and paste the text with proper formatting into the question.

Comment: So don’t use such a big number? Why do you need to use a number like that?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I'm testing to see if it's possible to have that number of posts in wp. that's really needed in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it is a JavaScript issue in WP!

[image]

As you see, it treats the post id `796978707878960019` as an integer but js cannot handle this bigint!
You can check this by typing the number in the console

[image]

Treating the post id as string in the wpLoadBlockEditor should solve the issue.

[image]

Found the source of the issue thanks to [**Mohsen Rabieai**](https://www.linkedin.com/in/mohsenrabieai/)

Answer (score 0):

The `ID` field in the `wp_post` table should be an **UNSIGNED BIGINT** in MySQL.

That means it can store values from 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 ((2^64)-1).

[See the MySQL documentation article for that](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html).

Your value of 796,978,707,878,960,002 is a not bigger than the allowed maximum value.
So in theory it should be able to handle that ID value, but the database clearly cannot handle values that big.

Check on the database: which version are you using, is it really an UNSIGNED BIGINT on your end?

Comment: I checked it on `mysqlnd 7.4.33` with `10.3.39-MariaDB` and also `mysqlnd 8.0.0` with `8.0.27`.
pardon me, I didn't get the "on your end" part. isn't it all handled by Wordpress? I checked the database and the wp_post table -> ID is UNSIGNED BIGINT. pls check the screenshot https://i.imgur.com/OJYrRCl.png